# can I merge 2 select in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 query

table1: item: `id/title`

table:2 tag: `id/item_id/name`

1-

```
   SELECT `*`
   FROM `item`
   INNER JOIN `tag` ON `item`.`id` = `tag`.`item_id`
   WHERE
   `tag`.`name` = 100;
```

2-

```
   SELECT `*`
   FROM `item`
   WHERE
   `title` = 100;
```

how can I join them (without duplicate `item` rows)?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  That way, we'll have some idea what you are trying to do.

Comment: This is a comment not a solution to your question, but you should not put `*` inside back-quotes, unless you have a column that is literally named `"*"` (which I would discourage).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you intend this:

```
select i.*
from item i
where i.title = 100 or
      exists (select 1 from tag t where i.id = t.item_id and t.name = 100);
```

This returns all items whose title is `100` or who have a tag `100`.

Answer (score 0):

Use OR modifier

`SELECT *
   FROM item
   INNER JOIN tag ON item.id = tag.item_id
   WHERE
   tag.name = 100 OR title=100;`

Answer (score 0):

table1: item: id/title
table:2 tag: id/item_id/name

```
SELECT *
   FROM item
   JOIN tag
 ON item.id = tag.item_id
   WHERE
   tag.name = 100 
 OR
   item.title= 100;
```

This will display BOTH tag names that are 100 and item titles that are 100.
Also SELECT `*` for selecting all columns should not be enclosed by single quotes. It is simply written as SELECT *